# retrieve simple products and product_variation with corcel

Tags: laravel, wordpress, woocommerce, corcel

In larvel I'm using [corcel](https://github.com/corcel/corcel) and with the help of this [comment](https://github.com/corcel/corcel) I'm trying to retrieve only simple products and variations of variable products.

```
$type = array('product_variation','product');
$status = 'publish';
$posts =
    \Corcel\Model\Post::
            type($type)->
            whereHas('taxonomies', function($q) {
                $q->where('taxonomy', 'product_type')
                ->whereHas('term', function($q) {
                    $q->where('slug', 'simple');
                })
                // since variations have no product_type taxonomy, then
                ->orwhere('taxonomy','<>', 'product_type');
            })->
            status($status)->
            latest()->
            limit(500)->
            get();
return $posts;
```

but it only returns product_variation(s), and no simple product. can some one please explain my wrong doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same problem, i realized that i can use `doesntHave`

```
$posts = \Corcel\Model\Post::status('publish')

       ->whereIn('post_type', ['product_variation','product']  )
       ->doesntHave('taxonomies')
       ->orWhereHas('taxonomies', function ($query) {
           $query->whereIn('taxonomy',['product_type'])
           ->whereHas('term', function($q) {
                                $q->where('slug', 'simple');
                            });
       })
    ->latest()
    ->limit(50)
    ->get();
   return $posts;
```